# How to fix cold start time issue

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, console, warnings

In my kotlin project, google play console one Warning issue in Performance is - "Your app took 5,793ms to launch for the first time, after being installed on this device model". Type is Cold start time. Can anyone help me to fix this issue. [image: I have attached the screenshot of this issue.]

Comment: How large is apk?

Comment: My apk size is 21.0MB

Comment: Do you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a variety of reasons, causing a slow startup. You should use a profiler to measure where the time is spent.

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

Very general there could be a lot of time spent on the CPU.
You could wait for a lot of network traffic to be received.
Or you initiate a very complex rendering, maybe requiring a lot of data to be loaded into memory.

One way of workaround would be to offload the initialisation into a background task, which is executed while the user is already a first screen presented, so they get a first visual feedback earlier.